# How do I send current month to jQuery FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use jquery [Full Calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar)

I could not find how I can retrieve the current month a user is on at a certain moment.

On render, it is set as the current month in the title, but I can't find a way to use that info. I want to send the month to my ajax call together with additional params (start, end, _) but I don't know how.

Inside the `fullcalendar` definition, how do I retrieve the month currently displayed?

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the really late response. here is what you would want:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/getDate/

Answer (score 1):

The following shows the current month in long format but can return many other formats:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate/

```
var curDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
alert("The current month of the calendar is " + $.fullCalendar.formatDate(curDate, "MMMM")); // Corrected the typo of currDate to curDate but thanks :)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', function (start, end, callback) {
            date = new Date(start);
            alert(date.getMonth());      

            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Employee/GetScheduleDetailedArray/',
                    async: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        id: 1,
                        currentDate: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate'),
                        currentMonth: date.getMonth()

                    },
                    success: function (doc) {
                        callback(doc);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        document.appendChild(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                }); //end ajax
        });
```

the function getMonth() will return an integer of the month.